# Hair dynamics in a moving car. What is the solution?

Tags: physics, hair, dynamic

I have a character with long hair in a moving car. The car is driving along and the hair is blowing back as if she was on a bike. I don't want this. How can I have dynamic hair (so it's falling naturally around her head) but stop the physics of the car affecting it? In a sense I want a forcefield surrounding the car in which gravity and forces act normally on her hair. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem in reality is one of 'frame of reference', so one solution could be to move the background instead of the car. :p

Answer (score 1):

I tried around a bit with a very basic hair system and the Field Weights settings and I think I found a solution.

Under "Hair Dynamics"->"Structure" crank Damping up to a very high number (I used over 100). Then go to "Field Weights" and max out Gravity. The slider only goes to 1, but if you type it in manually, it can go to 200.

If it's not enough Gravity, increase it in "Scene Properties", but that probably messes up other sims.

Hope this helps :)